# Capturing Continuous Frames and merging them as one in java

Tags: java, flash-builder, flv, xuggle

I am pretty new to image capturing using java. Just started working in java.

- What i want to ask is i have two `flv` videos i will like to combine. I searched the internet and many people said about `xuggler`.

I have a looked on it and did not found any documentation or tutorial regarding this.

- I do have it that i will have to capture frames continuously and than
  add each frame with each other as i want a `picture in picture video`
  and than form the video from those frames.

---

Please can anyone help me out here , how to capture continuous frames from an `flv` file and join them so a new video output can be obtained. Any hint or tutorial will be great. Thank you. I am using adobe flash builder and red5.

Comment: To be clear, by "combine" you mean appending one to the other? Or interlacing, composing or even something else?

Comment: u can see two videos in one tab, means both videos running in one video simultaneously. But i have done so. I have actually combined two videos and then their audios too. Both saved in OutputVideo.flv and OutputAudio.mp3. I am facing the problem now, how to join these two files into one video file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to tutorials to get started on Xuggle I suggest that you take a look at Xuggle Wiki. This [page](http://wiki.xuggle.com/MediaTool_Introduction) should help you to understand basic use of video encoding/decoding.
Then you should be able to adapt the source code of examples. I think you could use [this example](http://code.google.com/p/xuggle/source/browse/trunk/java/xuggle-xuggler/src/com/xuggle/mediatool/demos/ConcatenateAudioAndVideo.java) to combine your 2 flv files. Of course, you will need to change it to combine 2 video files.